# Make the outline of a input "red" if field is empty

Tags: primefaces

I use primefaces 4, template : cupertino.
I want to make the outline of a input "red" if field is empty.
I upgraded to type field  required = "true", but the outline remain in their original state if they are empty.
But for fields of type HTML 5 all goes well.

[image]

Thank you.

```
<form id="form_inscri_pp" name="form_inscri_pp">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5"  >
        <h:outputText  value="Nom:" styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
        <input  id="nom_pp" class='inscription_candidat' 
                placeholder='Saisissez votre nom' type='text' name="nom_pp"
                pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$" maxlength="25" required="required" 
                autocomplete="on"/>

        <h:outputText   value="Date de naissance: " styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
        <p:calendar name="DN_pp" id="DN_pp" value="#{calendrier.date}"  
                    locale="fr"  showOn="button" navigator="true" 
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="1/1/1950" maxdate="31/12/1993" 
                    mask="true" required="true" readonly="true"  size="20" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <input class='button_inscri'  type='submit' value="S'inscrire" />  
    <input class='button_inscri'  type='button' value='Réinitialiser' />
</form>
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Hello, I apply the code

Comment: Do you mean the calendar input or all the input?

Comment: only the calendar input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the code you post, the input text with id `nom_pp` get red-outlined when I input nothing. The only thing that won't work is `p:calendar`, which is because you put a `readonly` attribute in it.

So the solution is simply **remove the `readonly` attribute** of the `p:calendar`.
And BTW, **there is no `name` attribute** in `p:calendar`, so remove it, too.

What's more, you need to use `<h:form>` instead of `<form>`. And there is also no `name` parameter in `<h:form>`.
So you code should looks like:

```
    <h:form id="form_inscri_pp" >

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5"  >
            <h:outputText  value="Nom:" styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
            <input  id="nom_pp" class='inscription_candidat' 
                    placeholder='Saisissez votre nom' type='text' name="nom_pp"
                    pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$" maxlength="25" required="required" 
                    autocomplete="on"/>

            <h:outputText   value="Date de naissance: " styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
            <p:calendar id="DN_pp" value="#{inputValidateBean.date}"  
                        locale="fr"  showOn="button" navigator="true" 
                        pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="1/1/1950" maxdate="31/12/1993" 
                        mask="true" required="true" size="20" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <input class='button_inscri'  type='submit' value="S'inscrire" />  
        <input class='button_inscri'  type='button' value='Réinitialiser' />
    </h:form>
```

---

### UPDATE

Since the solution above doesn't work in your environment, try to replace all HTML5 components to primeface/jsf components.
I tried that and it also works in my environment.
Take a look at this:

```
<h:form id="form_inscri_pp" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5"  >
        <h:outputText  value="Nom:" styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
        <p:inputText id="nom_pp" styleClass="inscription_candidat" 
                     placeholder="Saisissez votre nom" maxlength="25"
                     required="true" autocomplete="on" value="#{inputValidateBean.nom}">
                 <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" />
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputText   value="Date de naissance: " styleClass="label_inscri_pp"/>
        <p:calendar id="DN_pp" value="#{inputValidateBean.date}"  
                    locale="fr"  showOn="button" navigator="true" 
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="1/1/1950" maxdate="31/12/1993" 
                    mask="true" required="true" size="20" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton styleClass="button_inscri" value="S'inscrire" 
                     validateClient="true" update="form_inscri_pp" 
                     action="#{inputValidateBean.doSubmit()}"/>
</h:form>
```

In the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InputValidateBean implements Serializable{
private Date date;
private String nom;

public void doSubmit(){
    System.out.println("Do something!");
}
//getters and setters below...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried your code but I met the same result

Comment: Try enter something into other input but leave the calendar empty.

Comment: Similarly p: calendar does not change color outline

Comment: It's weird because these code works in my environment.I'll try another solution.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved as soon as I removed the attribute "styleClass" p: calendar

Comment: So, did you try that with my first answer or updated answer? Or none of both?